# How can I create a Tensorboard for my Project?

Tags: python, keras, tensorboard

I am trying to create a Tensorboard for a dogs and cats classification but it fails to create a directory.

For some reason if I remove the .format(NAME) it runs for a second but then still throws and error. It manages to create this path:
logs -> train -> events.out.tfevents.1571558167.DESKTOP-TI1MJRC.2216.327.v2

```py
import pickle
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
import time

NAME = 'Cats-vs-dog-cnn-64x2{}'.format(int(time.time()))

tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir='logs/{}'.format(NAME))

...

model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, epochs=3, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[tensorboard])
```

if I leave the .format(NAME):

```
2019-10-20 10:04:05.020004: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1622] OP_REQUIRES failed at summary_kernels.cc:57 : Not found: Failed to create a directory: logs/Cats-vs-dog-cnn-64x21571558643\train; No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python/tensorflow/tutorial/cats_and_dogs.py", line 95, in <module>
    model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, epochs=3, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[tensorboard])
...
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Failed to create a directory: logs/Cats-vs-dog-cnn-64x21571558643\train; No such file or directory [Op:CreateSummaryFileWriter]
```

if I remove the .format(NAME):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\...\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 668, in on_start
    yield
...
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Failed to create a directory: logs/train\plugins\profile\2019-10-20_09-56-10; No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using:

```
import os

PATH = os.path.join('logs', NAME)
tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir=PATH)
```